# Convert JSON object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, reduce

I need to convert JSON object into different format.
My JSON looks like this -

```
{
  "approver": [ 
    {
      "roleId": "New Approver",
      "level": "1",
      "firstName": "Alan"
    },
    {
      "roleId": "New Approver",
      "level": "2",
      "firstName": "Alex"
    },
    {
      "roleId": "New Approver",
      "level": "1",
      "firstName": "Mike"
    },
    {
      "roleId": "USFA",
      "level": "1",
      "firstName": "Matt"
    },
    {
      "roleId": "USFA",
      "level": "1",
      "firstName": "John"
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected output:

```
  Output = [
   { roleName : "New Approver", 
     levels : [ 
      { level : "1", 
        users : ["alan", "mike"] }, 
     { level : "2", 
       users : ["alex"] }
    ] }, 
  { roleName : "USFA", 
    levels : [ 
    { level : "1", 
      users : ["matt", "john"] 
    }] 
}]
```

I have tried using reduce function but it does not give me expected results. Could anyone help me convert the object?

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't your output need to be an array of `Marketrole` objects? Your input has more than one `roleId` value, so it can't be mapped to a single `Marketrole` and the question doesn't make sense as is.

Comment: It's a big ask to have someone do your work for you.

Comment: Can you include full expected result at Question? What issue are you having resolving own inquiry?

Comment: Yes, Marketrole is an array of roleIds.

Comment: Please post your expected output in the question itself. It is not readable at all in the comments.

Comment: Your expected output has comments in the middle of it. It's not a valid object.

Answer (score 0):

How about try like Array.from(JSON_object_here)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was able to do it using reduce and map function.

Comment: @user2924113 Can you please post your map and reduce function as an answer to this post so that future readers can also benefit from it?